# Need help on navigation sidebar and content CSS

Tags: html, css

Ok so on my webpage, I have a left navigation, the position if fixed and when i want to add my content on the index page, the content appears behind the navigation and does not start after it.

If I remove the fixed position then it just goes underneath.

**Navigation CSS**

```
#nav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 18%;
    background-color: #1C1C1C;
    position: fixed;

}
```

I even tried putting all the content inside a div but no luck.

**Content DIV**

```
#padding {
height: auto;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
```

**Screenshots**

[image]

Comment: you want your text appear beside your navbar instead of behind or underneath is that right?

Comment: Yes:) It either goes behind or down below I can't get my content to the side:P

Comment: Add a `margin-left: 18%` to the content div?

Comment: Is that the best way to do it? Someone told me that's not a good way to put my whole content of a page inside a div, is there a way for anything to automatically display next to the nav?

Comment: It is best practise to use html markup elements like divs to set up your html site. There is no reason why you shouldn't put the hole content in a div element.

Answer (score 3):

Just put your content inside a div:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="nav">
         <!-- your navbar markup -->
    </div>
    <div id="content">
         <!-- your content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

with css you can style your elements:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
}
#nav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 18%;
    background-color: #1C1C1C;
    float: left;
}
#content {
    width: 82%;
    float: left;
}
```

With `float: left` your two divs appears aside.

NOTE:

If you don't want to put your content inside a div element, so just `float` your navbar element:

```
#nav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 18%;
    background-color: #1C1C1C;
    float: left;
}
```

...that's all and all following content appears (if possible) on the right side of your navbar.

Answer (score 0):

I would do `margin-left:18%;` or slightly higher on a container around your content. Then your content container will always be padded where the nav sits and will appear beside it.

Comment: Alright thankyou, wasn't sure whether this was the best way to go about doing it.